# Loop with function as parameter Handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have to do something like this in Handlebars.

```
var loopTimes=10-(array1.lenght+array2.lenght);
for (var i=0; i<loopTimes; i++) {
    <td></td>
}
```

Now I have the following code to do the loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Handlebars.registerHelper('times', function(n, block) {
        var accum = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            accum += block.fn(i);
        return accum;
    });
</script>
```

Then I call "times" function in the template.

```
{{#each data}}
    {{#each array1}}
        <td>{{this}}</td>
    {{/each}}
    {{#each array2}}
        <td>{{this}}</td>
    {{/each}}
    {{#times loopTimes}}
        <td></td>
    {{/times}}
{{/each}}
```

But I don't know how to set "loopTimes" variable. I try to create 2 functions plus and minus, like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('plus', function(n, s) {
    return n+s;
});
Handlebars.registerHelper('minus', function(n, s) {
    return n-s;
});
```

And the in the template I have this to calculate the value of loop parameter:

```
{{#times minus 10 plus array2.length array2.lenght}}
    <td></td>
{{/times}}
```

But, the minus has no effect. Template never evaluates minus value, and of course never enter in plus function. I tried to put brackets to separate each function (also with parenthesis or quotes), but if I do this, then I have an error in javascript when Handlebars try to create the html code because it doesn't match with the expected structure.

I can create a field "loopTimes" in javascript and set it to data object. I think it's the easiest solution, but it's very slowly because I can get a data array of 10.000 elements, and I had to get all elements to set this field. So I prefer to do this in the template if it's possible.

Someone can help me? Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Is `length` actually spelled right in your code, or was that just a typo when you posted the question? You have `lenght` in a couple places.

Comment: It's ok in the code. It was a mistake when i wrote this. But in the code is  `length`